# Wordpress theme customization : CSS class not found

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, themes

I try to customize a free version of a common wordpress theme (EmpowerWP), I have done a search on all the file of the website to find a specific CSS class : impossible to find !

so I see only two options :
1 - this CSS class is in the data base ?
2 - this CSS class is generated with php or javascript ?

if it's the case number 2, could it be a protection because this theme is also available on a pay version ? could it be encrypted ?

I really need to edit this CSS I cannot keep it like it is now,
I would like to avoid to change theme because I really like this one

Comment: You can use your browsers dev tools. It should show you where the style is defined!?

Comment: Can you share which class/id you are trying to change or any screenshot so we can answer this better?

Answer (score 0):

No one in the right minds will definitely put CSS in DB. You can ignore this option.

Check functions.ph file in the themes folder. Look for code like

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css');
```

This is how a CSS file is linked.

The class can also be added through Javascript.
So if you can share more info then I can guide on it.